# How to make an SVG responsive progress bar for web and mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making an app and I want to have a responsive SVG progress bar.
My code is below, but the progress bar is not responsive. How can I achieve responsiveness?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg  version="1.1" height="200"  width="850" y="0" x="0">
         <g>
            <defs>
               <linearGradient spreadMethod="reflect" y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="myLinearGradient3">
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#D7565A" offset="10%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="25%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="26%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="57%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#FFF34D" offset="58%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="77%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#4dd4ff" offset="78%"/>
               </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <!--  Gradient table -->
            <rect style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient3); stroke: #8D99A6; stroke-width: 0.5;" ry="10" rx="10" height="20" width="800" y="100" x="25"/>
         </g>
         <!--  Ruler   -->
         <!--    ballons    -->
         <g>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="45">(++)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="795">(--)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="40">DEFICIENT</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="255">SUB-NORMAL</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="445">NORMAL</text>
            <!--  movable vertical lines  : user exact value with ballon -->
            <!--  line 1  --> 
         </g>
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a viewBox to create responsive SVG. I've made the height and width 100% too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 4000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
         <g>
            <defs>
               <linearGradient spreadMethod="reflect" y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="myLinearGradient3">
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#D7565A" offset="10%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="25%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="26%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="57%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#FFF34D" offset="58%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="77%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#4dd4ff" offset="78%"/>
               </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <!--  Gradient table -->
            <rect style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient3); stroke: #8D99A6; stroke-width: 0.5;" ry="10" rx="10" height="20" width="800" y="100" x="25"/>
         </g>
         <!--  Ruler   -->
         <!--    ballons    -->
         <g>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="45">(++)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="795">(--)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="40">DEFICIENT</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="255">SUB-NORMAL</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="445">NORMAL</text>
            <!--  movable vertical lines  : user exact value with ballon -->
            <!--  line 1  --> 
         </g>
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I did that same and its working fine as required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did :

- Removed the svg's `width` and `height`
- Added a `viewbox` - read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)
- Gave the SVG an absolute position and wrap it inside a `container` - See [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/) for more examples

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  y="0" x="0" viewBox="0 0 850 200">
         <g>
            <defs>
               <linearGradient spreadMethod="reflect" y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="myLinearGradient3">
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#D7565A" offset="10%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="25%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="26%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="57%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#FFF34D" offset="58%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="77%"/>
                  <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#4dd4ff" offset="78%"/>
               </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <!--  Gradient table -->
            <rect style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient3); stroke: #8D99A6; stroke-width: 0.5;" ry="10" rx="10" height="20" width="800" y="100" x="25" />
         </g>
         <!--  Ruler   -->
         <!--    ballons    -->
         <g>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="45">(++)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="795">(--)</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="40">DEFICIENT</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="255">SUB-NORMAL</text>
            <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="445">NORMAL</text>
            <!--  movable vertical lines  : user exact value with ballon -->
            <!--  line 1  --> 
         </g>
      </svg>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All html5 elements are quite responsive, you just need to change all **width and Xcoordinate** - from PX values into %

```
  <svg  version="1.1" height="200"  width="100%" y="0" x="0">
     <g>
        <defs>
           <linearGradient spreadMethod="reflect" y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="myLinearGradient3">
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#D7565A" offset="10%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="25%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#E58E5F" offset="26%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="57%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#FFF34D" offset="58%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#EAEAEA" offset="77%"/>
              <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#4dd4ff" offset="78%"/>
           </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <!--  Gradient table -->
        <rect style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient3); stroke: #8D99A6; stroke-width: 0.5;" ry="10" rx="10" height="20" width="94%" y="100" x="5%"/>
     </g>
     <!--  Ruler   -->
     <!--    ballons    -->
     <g>
        <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="5.6%">(++)</text>
        <text text-anchor="start" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" y="137" x="94%">(--)</text>
        <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="5%">DEFICIENT</text>
        <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="31.87%">SUB-NORMAL</text>
        <text text-anchor="start" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gotham-Book" stroke-width="1" fill="#8B97A3" y="95" x="55.62%">NORMAL</text>
        <!--  movable vertical lines  : user exact value with ballon -->
        <!--  line 1  --> 
     </g>
  </svg>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/vnt6ys2b/1/)

Cheers,

Ashok

Comment: All the words stay the same size and eventually overlap when the screen width is small.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the comment but I believe there is no overlap issue till 320px which is the least width for any modern device. Moreover I have also ensured that texts are legible. Because when you create mask it makes it hardly readable which is happening in your case. We should never use mask instead use % for such cases.